# Graphing the locus of points a unit distance from a rectangular prism

Tags: plotting, regions, geometry, mesh

I am a new Mathematica user.

For one of my first projects, I am attempting to graph the locus of all points that are a unit distance from a rectangular prism with given dimensions.

I have no idea how to do this, except potentially graphing the components of the graph individually (eight eighth-spheres, 12 quarter-cylinders, and a rectangular prism). This seems very tedious.

I would appreciate it if anyone helped me to do this.

```
p2 = {Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}
p1 = {Ball[{0, 0, 10}, 1]}
p3 = {Ball[{4, 0, 10}, 1]}
p4 = {Ball[{4, 8, 10}, 1]}
p5 = {Ball[{0, 8, 0}, 1]}
p6 = {Ball[{0, 8, 10}, 1]}
p7 = {Ball[{4, 0, 0}, 1]}
p8 = {Ball[{4, 8, 0}, 1]}

Show[Graphics3D[p1], Graphics3D[p2], Graphics3D[p3], Graphics3D[p4], 
 Graphics3D[p5], Graphics3D[p6], Graphics3D[p7], Graphics3D[p8], 
 Graphics3D[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 8, 10}]] , 
 Graphics3D[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 8, 10}]] , 
 Graphics3D[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {0, 8, 10}]] PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code about `rectangular prism` and something you have try.

Comment: Sorry, what does this mean?

Comment: For example ,what is `rectangular prism` ?`Graphics3D[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {3, 4, 5}], Boxed -> False]`?  We need to post the Mathematica code in this forum.

Comment: Sure that is rectangular prism. Sorry, im new here

Comment: Stack sites do not provide free coding services, design assistance, tutorials or homework solutions. From the perspective of community members who volunteer their time to answer questions, any poster (who does not show effort) could be providing one of these paid services to a third party (or not). Hence, it is important that you include the work that you have done so far as Mathematica code. That is the rationale anyways and it helps prevent site abuse.

Comment: I do not want a code.. I just want a hint. I am new to Mathematica. Did I not already say what I tried? I tried using Graphics3D to individually plot 8 spheres, 12 cylinders, and 1 (+6) cuboids. However I quickly got tired of this and I would like to know if there is an easier way. Am i in the wrong place? Edit: Is it my originally wording  which implied I wanted someone to write the code for me? Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- One way is `RegionDilation` according to a unit ball `Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]`.

```
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Yellow], EdgeForm[], 
  RegionDilation[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 8, 10}], Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- Or defined a `RegionDistanceFunction` and use `ContourPlot3D` to draw the level set equal to `1`.

```
Clear[reg, dist];
reg = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 8, 10}];
dist = RegionDistance@reg;
ContourPlot3D[
 dist@{x, y, z} == 1, {x, -2, 6}, {y, -2, 10}, {z, -2, 12},BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

- We can also use the function `OpenCascadeShapeFillet` in `OpenCascadeLink`. But we need to expand the `Cuboid[{0,0,0},{x,y,z}]` to `Cuboid[{-r, -r, -r}, {x + r, y + r, z + r}]]` at first.

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
r = 1;
{x, y, z} = {4, 8, 10};
shape = OpenCascadeShape[
   Cuboid[{-r, -r, -r}, {x + r, y + r, z + r}]];
fillet = OpenCascadeShapeFillet[shape, r];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[fillet, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> 0.1}];
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"] /@ Subdivide[Length@groups];
bmesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive@{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[#]} & /@ 
     colors)]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to make the components of the solid appear individuakly?

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
c1 = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 8, 10}];
df = RegionDistance[c1];
reg[r_] := ImplicitRegion[df[{x, y, z}] <= r, {x, y, z}]

Show[
 Region[Style[reg[1], Opacity[0.5, Lighter@Blue]]]
 , Region[Style[c1, Opacity[0.5, Lighter@Red]]]
 ]
```

[image]